# javascript, how to get a value from XML

Tags: javascript, c#, xml

I'm learning how to use javascript to call web method from ASMX service using XMLHttpRequest class. I've managed to write the following:

```
function GetDataService() {
            if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
                xmlHTTP = new window.XMLHttpRequest;
            } else {
                alert("Wrong!");
            }

            xmlHTTP.open("POST", "http://localhost:45250/ServiceJava.asmx", true);
            xmlHTTP.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "text/xml; charset=utf-8");
            xmlHTTP.setRequestHeader("SOAPAction", "http://localhost:45250/ServiceJava.asmx/GetTimeString");

            strRequest = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>';
            strRequest = strRequest + '<soap:Envelope '
                + 'xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" '
                + 'xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" '
                + 'xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">';
            strRequest = strRequest + '<soap:Body>';
            strRequest = strRequest + '<GetTimeString xmlns="http://localhost:45250/ServiceJava.asmx" />';
            strRequest = strRequest + '</soap:Body>';
            strRequest = strRequest + '</soap:Envelope>';

            //Different value for readystate
            //0--Uninitialized
            //1--Loading
            //2--loaded(but data not recieved)
            //3--Interactive--Some part of the data is recieved
            //4--Completed(all data recieved)
            xmlHTTP.onreadystatechange = function () {
                if (xmlHTTP.readyState == 4 && xmlHTTP.status == 200) {
                    var x = xmlHTTP.responseXML;
                    document.getElementById("time").textContent = x;                  
                }
            }
            xmlHTTP.send(strRequest);
        }
```

But it produces the code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"><soap:Body><GetTimeStringResponse xmlns="http://localhost:45250/ServiceJava.asmx"><GetTimeStringResult>14:31:28</GetTimeStringResult></GetTimeStringResponse></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>
```

Now I would like to get only the `14:31:28`. How can I do that? I've tried to find the answer but `x` doesn't seem to have method like `getElementByTagName()` or anything similiar.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution without using jQuery

```
var xmlStr = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><soap:Envelope ...';    
var xml = new window.DOMParser().parseFromString(xmlStr, "text/xml");   
var value = xml.getElementsByTagName("GetTimeStringResult")[0].innerHTML;
```

Comment: I've accepted this answer because it's not using `jQuery` and for that particular reason I needed that. Yet I have some question... If my `xmlStr` was from `(..).responseXML` so why should I make a string, then again convert it to XML and finally use `getElement...`? Why wasn't I able to work on original XML? Is it readonly or something?

Comment: It seems you might have to set the Content-Type header to text/xml: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/responseXML

Comment: It says `If the server doesn't specify the Content-Type header as text/xml or application/xml, you can use overrideMimeType() to force XMLHttpRequest to parse it as XML anyway.`
The thing is that server specifies the Content-Type as `text/xml`, so it's kind of weird.

Answer (score 1):

You can use for example the [jQuery parseXML](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseXML/) method.

```
var response = "<?xml version="1.0" encodi...";
var xml= $($.parseXML(response));
var value = xml.find("GetTimeStringResult").text();
```

However, if you choose to send the request with jQuery instead of vanilla javascript, you get the response already deserialized in the callback.

Comment: As I've written above I was "forced" to use vanilla javascript. But since I've received the result then I think I might use `jQuery` to get my result.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend that you don't write the XMLHttpRequests by hand. Instead use jQuery.ajax():

```
$.ajax({
    url: "http://localhost:45250/ServiceJava.asmx/GetTimeString",
    type: "POST",
    data:  postData,
    success: function(data, textStatus, jqXhr) {
             var result = data.GetTimeStringResult;
    }
});
```

'postData' should be a JSON object in which you pass your parameters to your endpoint.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the information. Unfortunately, it is my task to use this class, otherwise I would look into `jQuery` I guess:)

Comment: Internally, jQuery.ajax() also creates an XMLHttpRequest, it just frees you from handling the SOAP XML directly.